# Order List by external variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a list where users can see which other use has the most interests in common. 
I've already created all the classes and the number output is correct but i don't know how to sort the list, so the people with the most interests in common (highest numbers) are on top of the list, while the ones without many (lowest numbers) are on the bottom.

My code for inserting the values into the webpage looks like this:

```
$currentUserInterest = $interestutil->getCurrentUserInterest()->interestlist;
$otherUsersInterest = $interestutil->getAllOtherUserInterest();
foreach ($otherUsersInterest as $key => $user) 
{
    $commonInterests =count($currentUserInterest) - count(array_diff($currentUserInterest, $user->interestlist));
    echo "<li>" . $user->fname . " " . $user->lname ." $commonInterests gemeinsame Interessen</span>";
}
```

If someone of you could tell me a way with html/javascript/jquery/php to sort this list it would help me really much.

Thanks and Cheers

Jutschge

Comment: We're going to need more information. How do you want it sorted? What does the unsorted data look like (give us a small, but complete example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to loop through all the users, building up an array of `$commonInterests`, sort that array, then output the users in the order of the sorted `$commonInterests` array:

```
$currentUserInterest = $interestutil->getCurrentUserInterest()->interestlist;
$otherUsersInterest = $interestutil->getAllOtherUserInterest();

$commonInterests = array();
foreach ($otherUsersInterest as $key => $user) {
    // You can use `array_intersect` instead of `array_diff` here.
    $commonInterests[$key] = count(array_intersect($currentUserInterest, $user->interestlist));
    //$commonInterests[$key] = count($currentUserInterest) - count(array_diff($currentUserInterest, $user->interestlist));
}

// This sort function preserves each $key, whereas `sort` would rekey the array.
// It will sort in increasing order (i.e. 1, 2, 3...). For decreasing order
// (i.e. 3, 2, 1...) use `arsort` instead.
asort($commonInterests);

foreach ($commonInterests as $key => $commonInterestsCount) {
    $user = $otherUsersInterest[$key];

    echo "<li>{$user->fname} {$user->lname} $commonInterestsCount gemeinsame Interessen</span>";
}
```